# Finding descendants of great-grandfather in Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine

I hired a researcher who traced my grandfathers family from 1795 to 1922.

His father passed away in 1922 from an asthma attack and his family moved from the village soon after but I have not been able to find any records.

I have written to a number of archives in Ukraine without any luck.

My grandfather passed away before I was born and I was wondering if anyone knew of any other resources that I can use to try and locate descendants from his brothers and sisters.

---

The report listed my grandfathers siblings etc and the researcher looked at records until the 1940's but there were no births, marriages or deaths for anyone in my grandfathers family. He found the records at the archives in Busk. The village that my grandfather was born in was Tur'ya, Lviv Oblast, Ukraine which is about 90 kms from Lviv. The researcher went to the village and spoke to people and took a video of the house where my grandfather was born, but nobody knew where they moved to. I think all of my grandfathers siblings have passed away so I would be looking for their children.

Comment: Hi Maria, welcome! You may get a more specific response if you include the village name or at least the general area - Ukraine is a big country and the borders have changed many times over the years, so determining where records are can sometimes be tricky.

Comment: I think what you are asking for help in tracing (potentially) living persons in Ukraine (and elsewhere, if any of the family emigrated). Did your researcher provide documentation, including archive citations and names of his contacts for records,  for his work? Did the report include the siblings' names or was it limited to your ancestors? The report would be your starting point and you may have to contact him again for further information and advice.